# Selenium chrome error

Tags: python, selenium, screen-scraping

I get this error when trying to open chrome with selenium.

I have already updated my chrome driver.
Any ideas?

> WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Devtools port number file contents <50957> were in an unexpected format

I do not understand how this is a duplicate, looking at the other forum I see all the solutions to the problem written in a different programming language, and the 1 python solution doesn't work. Also that error is caused when he tries to load a URL, my error is caused when I try to define my browser.

Comment: can you show your code ?

Comment: chromedriver = "C:/Users/iza/desktop/chromedriver/chromedriver.exe"
os.environ["webdriver.chrome.driver"] = chromedriver
browser = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)

Comment: My code's not the problem, I'm moving the script to a different computer so I can run it 24/7. it works fine on the other PC. I also updated selenium forgot to mention that

Comment: @lzakMarshall How did you solve the issue? I have got the same error.